# NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I execute multiple requests asynchronously and each response returns an xml. I need to extract the xml (I’m using TBXML to parse it) and save it in Core Data. This cannot be done on the main thread because the UI will get too slow.
I’m doing the following for each xml response:

```
dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.queue.name", NULL);
dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{
      AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      NSManagedObjectContext *newMOC = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
      [newMOC setPersistentStoreCoordinator:[appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
      newMOC setUndoManager:nil];

      NSNotificationCenter *notify = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
      [notify addObserver:self 
            selector:@selector(mergeChanges:) 
            name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification 
            object:newMOC];
      [self traverseElement:tbxml.rootXMLElement inMOC:newMOC];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:newMOC];
      [newMOC release];
});
dispatch_release(request_queue);

- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification*)notification 
{
    AppDelegate *theDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[theDelegate managedObjectContext] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:) withObject:notification 
    waitUntilDone:YES];
```

}

In the traverseElement method, I parse the xml and insert the data in Core Data.
I’m getting a lot of merge conflicts like the one below when executing this. Any ideas why or any clues to debug this issue? I haven’t changed the Core Data model.

```
NSMergeConflict for NSManagedObject with objectID '...' 
with oldVersion = 117 and newVersion = 118 and 
old object snapshot = ... and new cached row =  ...
```

Comment: Can you give a short description of what your traverseElement does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge conflict encapsulates conflicts that occur when attempting to save changes in a managed object context.

There are two situations in which a conflict may occur:

Between the managed object context and its in-memory cached state at the persistent store coordinator layer. In this case, the merge conflict has a source object and a cached snapshot but no persisted snapshot.

Between the cached state at the persistent store coordinator and the external store (file, database, etc.). In this case, the merge conflict has a cached snapshot and a persisted snapshot.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSMergeConflict_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010688) here.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSMergeConflict_Class/Reference/Reference.html need citation

Comment: @LuongHuyDuc Good point - this was a while ago though. I fixed it. No need to down-vote, though.

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful to you: http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/11/using-core-data-on-multiple-threads/.

The article explains how you should multithread for persistency.